# the purpose of using protected attributes Python

Tags: python, inheritance, protected

I'm learning Python, I've coded a bit in C++ before. I have simple very code:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self._mark = mark


class Bus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.audi = Car("Audi")

    def display(self):
        print(self.audi._mark)

def main():
    bmw = Car("BMW")
    print(bmw._mark)

    reno = Bus()
    reno.display()

main()
```

As far as I know in C++, only classes that inherit have access to "protected" attributes. So my questions:

- What is the purpose of using "protected" attributes / methods in Python?
- Why do I have access to the attribute `_mark` from the main function/class `Bus`?

Thank you for explain!

Comment: There's no access control happening. All names in Python are public (with a bit of magic changing the name as per the name mangling link above). The `_` thing is a convention that Python programmers generally respect, but it's not one that the runtime enforces.

Comment: so using `_` only gives a suggestion to the programmer that the attribute should not be modified outside of the class. And it has no effect on using in code?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Not

Comment: @AnnAc0nda, right, it's just a convention. It tells the developer they're using an interface that isn't guaranteed to work in the future so their program may break and it'll be their fault.